# Is there any easy way to animate a Wrap widget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I want to use a Wrap widget that I can remove and add items in it, and I want its children's positions to be animated whenever the items change. But it seems like there is no supported and easy way to do that like a AnimatedList, AnimatedContainer, etc...

I'm looking for a solution like a library, a guide or an elegant way to do that.
Can anyone help me so I can really save tons of work to achieve that goal? Thank you so much!!!

Comment: try https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_animate